# Could a large constrictor kill a small animal?

Tags: zoology, snake

According to [this article](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2003/dec/30/indonesia.johnaglionby) there was a python whose body circumference was 85cm.  This means its diameter was 27cm.

Would it be possible for this snake to constrict animals that are about the same size as its diameter?  It is hard to imagine it having enough flexibility to constrict a swamp rat, for example, whose size is less than 27cm.  Could it kill such animals by another method, say with its jaws or by crushing them by rolling over them?  Or are such small animals simply off its target list?

Answer (score 3):

Constrictors doesn't have uniform body circumference from head to tail. They coil around the prey accordingly. In your example, if the prey is very small, it just swallows. If its little big, it coils a little bit (check some videos like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8Ie5klOijs)) say two turn coil. This will only cover top half feet of constrictor's length which is of lesser diameter than the body.

So basically, they crush the prey and perform a kill. Its not a necessity for any constrictor to use its entire body to coil around a prey. They adjust their coil level to control the prey.